add after_save callback on the instance level
Is it possible to add instance-level callbacks to rails models?
class MyModel << ActiveRecord::Base

  def some_stuff(...)
    (...)
    self.foo = "bar"
    after_save { MyWorker.perform_async(self.id) } # Needs to see MyModel.find(id).foo == "bar", but this is not accepted.
  end
end


You could set up a normal after_save callback that looks for a special flag on the instance, but this feels like an XY Problem. What is the problem you're trying to solve with instance level callbacks? There may be a better solution.

I could,  i was wondering if there was an out of the box solution for it.

I am trying to enqueue some sidekiq jobs to sync model state to different backends on aasm model state transitions, but those callbacks get triggered before actually saving the model

You can accomplish this with a normal callback which looks for a special flag on the instance.
class MyModel << ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save do
    MyWorker.perform_async(self.id) if @perform_my_worker_after_save
  end

  def some_stuff
    self.foo = "bar"
    @perform_my_worker_after_save = true
  end
end


I was wondering if there was an out of the box solution for this.  But yeah,  i was thinking about something similar with saving an array of lambdas to execute.

Wound up with this:
module InstanceHooks
  HOOKS = [
    :before_validation,
    :after_validation,
    :before_save,
    :after_save,
    :after_commit,
    :after_destroy_commit,
    :after_update_commit,
    :after_save_commit,
    :after_rollback
  ]

  # TODO: Use a hash instead
  def self.ivar_name(hook)
    "@#{hook}_hooks"
  end

  def self.ivar_name_once(hook)
    "@#{hook}_hooks_once"
  end

  def self.define_hook(hook)
    ivar = self.ivar_name(hook)

    define_method(hook) do |&block|
      instance_variable_set(ivar, (instance_variable_get(ivar) || []) + [block])
    end

    ivar_once = self.ivar_name_once(hook)
    define_method("#{hook}_once".to_sym) do |&block|
      instance_variable_set(ivar_once, instance_variable_get(ivar_once) || [] + [block])
    end
  end


  HOOKS.each { |hook| define_hook(hook) }

  def self.included(base)
    HOOKS.each do |hook|
      ivar = self.ivar_name(hook)
      ivar_once = self.ivar_name_once(hook)

      base.class_eval do
        method(hook).call do |*args, **kwargs, &block|
          hooks = instance_variable_get(ivar) || []
          once_hooks = instance_variable_get(ivar_once) || []
          (hooks + once_hooks).each do |hook|
            hook.call(*args, **kwargs, &block)
          end

          instance_variable_set(ivar_once, [])
        end
      end
    end
  end
end



It's very clever, but also metaprogramming a pile of callbacks seems rather complicated for the underlying issue of synchornizing jobs. I'd suggest asking another question about your underlying problem, tag me on it and I'll have a look.

You are missing a parenthesis in the method body definitions. instance_variable_set(ivar, instance_variable_get(ivar) || [] + [block]) should be instance_variable_set(ivar, (instance_variable_get(ivar) || []) + [block]) that being said in my opinion it would be alot cleaner to use a Hash and just store the hooks in that rather than possibly 18 different instance variables. e.g. {after_save: {hooks: [block1,block2], hooks_once: [block1]},...} it would also dramatically clean up the method definitions.

Yep, good catch! And yeah, probably better to use a hash.

There is an after_all_transactions_commit method that could be used here:
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  def do_something
    self.foo = "bar"
    ActiveRecord.after_all_transactions_commit do
      MyWorker.perform_async(id) 
    end
  end
end

# wrap it in a transaction to delay execution
Model.transaction do
  model.do_something
  model.save!
end
# job is scheduled after transaction is committed


"InstanceHooks" is also a nice approach, this is just a personal flavor:
# app/models/concerns/instance_callbacks.rb

#   class Model < ApplicationRecord
#     include InstanceCallbacks
#     def complete
#       self.status = "completed"
#       after_commit { CompleteJob.perform_later(self) if completed? }
#     end
#   end
#
#   model = Model.new
#   model.complete
#   model.save
#
module InstanceCallbacks
  def self.included base
    callbacks = [:after_save, :after_commit]
    callbacks.each do |callback_name|
      base.class_eval <<~CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
        def #{callback_name}(&block)
          _add_instance_callback(:#{callback_name}, &block)
        end

        #{callback_name} do
          _run_instance_callbacks(:#{callback_name})
        end
      CODE
    end
  end

  private

  def _instance_callbacks
    @_instance_callbacks ||= Hash.new([])
  end

  def _add_instance_callback callback_name, &block
    _instance_callbacks[callback_name] += [block]
  end

  def _run_instance_callbacks callback_name
    while callback = _instance_callbacks[callback_name].shift
      callback.call
    end
  end
end


I'll take a look at this approach. The first one wouldn't work in case you are not in a transaction though, would it?

@ÁkosVandra-Meyer correct, if you're not in a transaction the block given to after_all_transactions_commit would run immediately.
